# Why is my date not displaying properly?

Tags: java, javascript, date

I used SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
value.adStartDate = df.parse("2011/11/11 11:11:11");
```

I was hoping the date would come out like the string I provided, but instead I am getting this:

```
Fri Nov 11 2011 11:11:11 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

This is showing on a form that I created using Javascript...

Is there a way to "force" the output on the form to be like the string?

Basically I want to pass a date with format "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss" to a form that was generated using Javascript and have the form display it in that same format.

Comment: The problem is caused by the way how you passed that back to the HTML. After all, you need `SimpleDateFormat#format()` to convert `Date` to `String` in the desired pattern.

Comment: Are you using the Date for any intermediate purpose in your Java code? Because if not you are just adding a level of 'complexity' to your code for no added benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is parsing and another thing is formatting.

Check this example in order to display the formatted string.

```
@Test
    public void testDateFormat() throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
        Date myDate = df.parse("2011/11/11 11:11:11");
        System.out.println(df.format(myDate));
    }
```

Output:

> 2011/11/11 11:11:11

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to achieve? You have successfully parsed `"2011/11/11 11:11:11"` **`String`** into `java.util.Date` object. `Date.toString()` yields the string you see (*Fri Nov 11 2011 11:11:11 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)*).

If you now want to format the `Date` object back to `String`, use `df.format()` which does the opposite thing compared to `df.parse()`.

Comment: I thought that as well, but the `Date#toString()` has a bit different format. The year should be after the time. There's more happening here.

Comment: True, it's actually written in the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()): *dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy* - weird...

Comment: well basically i want to pass a date in "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss" format to a form and have that form display the date in that same format...

Comment: @Joe: use `format()` method to convert `Date` to `String`. The `Date` doesn't remember any format. All it holds is the epoch time. All its `toString()` does is printing a builtin and predefinied format (however, whatever you got is not the same, how were you passing it and what Java version are you using?)

Comment: No. You need to convert in Java before passing. JavaScript doesn't understand `java.util.Date` objects or something. All it understands from the server side are plain strings.